# How do I go about opening href link in a jQuery Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Okay, so I've got the following code shown below to create a dialog using a div within a particular page:

```
    $('#modal').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    height: 450,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    title: 'Enter Data',
    close: function() { 
        $("#modal .entry_date").datepicker('hide');
    } 
 });

 $('.modal').click(function() {
    $('#modal').dialog('open');
 });
```

It is all working fine. However,  now what I want to do is to also be able to open a link in a dialog window.  For example using 
something along the lines of the code below:

```
<a href="/path/to/file.html" class="modal">Open Me!!</a>
```

I've done this before by hardcoding the path as in the example code below:

```
$('#modal').load('/path/to/file.html').dialog('open');
```

In this case however, we can't hardcode the path in the javascript as there will be multiple items coming from the database.

At this point I'm struggling to understand how to get this to work. I'm also convinced that the answer is really obvious, and I'm merely setting myself up to be humbled by the clever folk here at StackOverflow.

I've scratched my head for long enough this afternoon, so my ego has been put away, and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction on how to code this properly.

Comment: Well the page has to know what the path is *somehow*, right? How does the page get that information?  When you have that answer, then your approach of using "load" before opening the dialog is pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just grab the href attribute and load that

```
$('.modal').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modal').load(this.href).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: That's done the trick. I knew you'd be able to get the href some how, but everything I tried opened the link regardless as it wasn't preventing the browser from opening the link first! Many, many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

In this code dialog size and title is declare in link

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function tb_parseQuery(query) {
        var Params = {};
        if (!query) { return Params; }// return empty object
        var Pairs = query.split(/[;&]/);
        for (var i = 0; i < Pairs.length; i++) {
            var KeyVal = Pairs[i].split('=');
            if (!KeyVal || KeyVal.length != 2) { continue; }
            var key = unescape(KeyVal[0]);
            var val = unescape(KeyVal[1]);
            val = val.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
            Params[key] = val;
        }
        return Params;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.uimodal').bind('click', function () {

        var $this = $(this);
        var url = $this.attr("href");



        var queryString = url.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/, '');
        var params = tb_parseQuery(queryString);
        TB_WIDTH = (params['width'] * 1) + 30 || 630; //defaults to 630 if no paramaters were added to URL
        TB_HEIGHT = (params['height'] * 1) + 40 || $(document).height(); //defaults to 440 if no paramaters were added to URL
            TB_Title = (params['title']);



        $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $(this).load(url);
            },
            height: TB_HEIGHT,
            width: TB_WIDTH,
            title: TB_Title
        });
        return false;
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a class="uimodal" href="Dialog.aspx?height=350&width=700&title=تست"> click</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Phil, you need to grab the `href` attribute:

```
var link = $('#modal').attr('href');
$('#modal').load(href).dialog('open');
```

Comment: You forgot to say that you need to disable the anchor tag from sending request to the server. That is done by stopping propagation on the browser by `preventDefault` or `return false;`